# How to use ng-if with radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This should be a simple question.

I'm having trouble using `ng-if` with radio buttons. These are my buttons:

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" id="day_month" ng-model="day_month" name="inlineRadioOptions" value="option1"> day of the
    month
</label>
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" id="day_week" ng-model="day_month" name="inlineRadioOptions" value="option2"> day of the
    week
</label>
```

How can I use `ng-if` to show something if the first radio button is selected?

Answer (score 3):

The binded model `day_month` will be updated upon select with the `value` of the input. Checking if the value equals to the value will give you the possibility to check whether the input has been selected. Please see the example below.

```
<label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" id="day_month" ng-model="day_month" name="inlineRadioOptions" value="option1"> day of the
    month
</label>
<label class="radio-inline" ng-show="day_month == 'option1'">
    <input type="radio" id="day_week" ng-model="day_month" name="inlineRadioOptions" value="option2"> day of the
    week
</label>
```

Comment: Is it with two equals or three? I.e. `==` or `===`? Either way, that doesn't work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that you used `ng-show`. Anyway, I tried it and it also didn't work. I have other conditions and they work fine with either `ng-if` or `ng-show`. It's only when I add this condition that it stops working.

Comment: See the jsfiddle for example. You can change the jsfiddle to make it match your problem se we can have a further look :)

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you need to show and hide some content based on selection of radio button. We can directly bind a Boolean value to check box and do it very easily. If you want do it with radio button please find below solution.
**HTML :**

```
<body ng-app=”app”>
<div ng-controller="PageController">
<label>
    <input type="radio"  ng-model="color.name" value="Red"> Red
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio"  ng-model="color.name" value="Green"> Green
</label><br>
<div ng-if="color.name==='Red'?true:false">
Hidden Message
</div> 
</body>
```

**Angualr controller:**

```
var app =angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("PageController",function($scope){
$scope.color={name:'Green'};

});
```

Working example
https://jsfiddle.net/mshyam83/q8vbbd8q/5/

Answer (score 1):

Your model will be updated with whatever value is in the `[value]` attribute, so you can check the data stored in whatever variable is specified by `ng-model`:

```
<div ng-if="day_month === 'option1'">...example...</div>
```

Comment: That's what I though I had to do, but that doesn't work for me, I don't know why. Does that work for you?